# Restore the edittext value in the first activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two `EditText` and a `Button` in the first activity. After entering the `EditText` values and clicking the button, the application navigates to the second activity. When returning back to the first activity, my `EditText` values are cleared but I need to display the given values in the `EditText`. Can anybody please suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: Store them in [SharedPreference](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html)

Answer (score 1):

Call Activity using `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()` and do not finish your first activity.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(YourFirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class),0);
```

**Edit : As Lucifer suggest store your edittext value in shared prefernce when you call second activity . In first activity onCreate() method after declaring edittext set the sharedPreference value.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNameToLaunch.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```